# Sort nvarchar column in t-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have nvarchar column with the following data:

```
1.0  
10.0      
10.1      
5.1       
6.4       
5.3       
90.5      
39.23     
23.2.2    
21.2.1    
4.3.1
```

When I order it as string I get the following result:

```
1.0       
10.0      
10.1      
21.2.1    
23.2.2    
39.23     
4.3.1     
5.1       
5.3       
6.4       
90.5  

select * from mytable order by mycolumn
```

which is wrong, it should sort the set as numeric, for example:

```
1.0
1.1
1.2
2.3
2.3.1
```

etc.

How can I sort it correctly? I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: "which is wrong," - no, that's how it's designed! :)

Comment: okay, then how to redesign it manually? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to sort by numbers, you *should* better store the data as numbers. Store the parts in three columns, then you can query `ORDER BY n1, n2, n3`.
You can add a `computed column` to return the complete string, e.g.  with the formula

```
=convert(nvarchar(10), n1) + '.' + convert(nvarchar(10), n2) + 
CASE WHEN n3 IS NOT NULL THEN '.' + 
convert(nvarchar(10), n3) ELSE '' END
```

Of course you could let the dbms disassemble a string and find and convert the parts to numbers on every query, but that would be 'slow' and inefficient.

**EDIT**

As in the link in Martin Smith's comment, and which I didn't know yet - you actually *can* do it directly with

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(HIERARCHYID, '/' + myColumn + '/')
```

Comment: Thank you, I had the same guess but hoped if there is another more effective way.

Comment: there is an error converting nvarchar into numeric, so 'ORDER BY CAST('/' + YourColumn + '/' AS HIERARCHYID)' works perfectly.